# php.ini overwrite from project.ini file

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Is it possible to separate my changes to the php.ini into a different file, which overwrite the default settings.

E.g in my project.ini I wanted to overwrite the maxlifetime?

```
; Overwrite PHP settings required for Project

[Session]
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

I have seen some open source websites are packages with the php.ini inside. Is this a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set php.ini values manually in php with `ini_set` which overwrites the default values. 
Put this line at the top of every page (before `session_start`) or put it in a php file which is included everytime:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
```

Check this page for more Information: [PHP: ini_set - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Additionally you can override ini values by using

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

in a `.htaccess` file which is described here:
[PHP: How to change configuration settings - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)